# Hot Code Push with Meteor 1.8.2 on Android

Tags: android, meteor

I am working on a Meteor project.

Since the update to Meteor `1.8.2`, I observe an abnormal behavior of the Hot Code Push mechanism.

On several `Android 9` devices:

- Hot Code Push works fine with the 4G network
- but **does not work with Wifi**

I can see the following error in the adb logs:

```
12-06 12:28:14.208 28814 28814 D SystemWebChromeClient: 
http://localhost:12096/__cordova/354735fa6f37511a22c6f370258b44c32ce1ad26.js?meteor_js_resource=true: Line 144 : WebSocket connection to 'wss://xxx.xxx.com/sockjs/133/x01eemtg/websocket' failed: 
WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.
```

On Android 5.1.1, everything works fine (with both 4G and Wifi).

I haven't found any forum post or documentation related to this specific problem... Any idea on this?